# SQL query need to get certain counts of data item

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

here is the whole picture. There is a table (table programparticipants) that stores all participants of all programs, there is another table (table programs) that stores all the programs. What I need to accomplish is the following:

1. Acquire the programs where a user has attended more than one program (done)
2. Acquire the other programs (from step 1) that a user attended based one one program
3. Acquire the count of occurences that of two programs being attended by users.

Example table (programparticipants)

```
UserID     Program
1          2
1          3
2          2
2          4
2          5
3          1
3          2
3          5
3          6
3          7
4          5  
4          6
4          7
5          4
5          5
5          6
5          7
```

Example output

- prog 2 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(3)
- prog 2 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 2 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(4)
- prog 2 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 2 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(6)
- prog 2 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 2 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(7)
- prog 2 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 4 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(2)
- prog 4 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 4 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(5)
- prog 4 - OCCURENCES (2)
- prog 4 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(6)
- prog 4 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 4 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(7)
- prog 4 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 5 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(4)
- prog 5 - OCCURENCES (2)
- prog 5 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(6)
- prog 5 - OCCURENCES (3)
- prog 5 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(7)
- prog 5 - OCCURENCES (3)
- prog 6 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(2)
- prog 6 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 6 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(5)
- prog 6 - OCCURENCES (3)
- prog 6 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(7)
- prog 6 - OCCURENCES (3)
- prog 7 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(2)
- prog 7 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 7 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(4)
- prog 7 - OCCURENCES (1)
- prog 7 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(5)
- prog 7 - OCCURENCES (3)
- prog 7 - ASSOCIATED PROGRAMS(6)
- prog 7 - OCCURENCES (3)

This will be going into a datagrid displaying something like:

```
      prog 1     prog 2     prog 3     prog 4     prog 5     prog 6     prog 7
prog 1             
prog 2                        1          1                     1          7
prog 3             1
prog 4             1                                2          1          1
prog 5                                   2                     3          3
prog 6             1                                3                     3
prog 7             1                     1          3          3
```

If anymore explaination is needed please let me know.

I do have existing code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL sorry everyone, I was actually acquiring the necessary data in the query, however I was taking into account that the queried program was returning itself as well. and I just have to add a counter to each program that is returned.

So I believe I can get it all to work now. Thank you though, and this site is AWESOME. I have had great help in the past week solve some issues that I have had

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is called a pivot table or crosstab report. How you implement it will depend on your RBDMS. Some databases such as Oracle have [built in functionality](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/09/pivot-and-crosstab-queries.html) to do this. In others such as MySQL you have to [do a little more work](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table).

Comment: This is a MS SQL database.  What I was actually planning on doing what acquiring the list of all programs where a user has attended more than one. Then take that list and perform a loop through each program and perform the queries and populate a datatable within C# to create it. Iknow it can be done I have seen it done this way, but all I need is the data and I can not for the life of me acquire the data I need, past step 1 above